# WebStorm 6.0 on MacOS 10.8.4 installation

Tags: webstorm

I'm trying to upgrade WebStorm from **5.0.4** to **6.0.2**.

First I deleted WebStorm 5 and deleted all related folders from `users/user/Library`.

After that I installed 6.0.2 (http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/index.html) an ran it as trial. It runs, I can see the sign "WebStorm" in the top left corner next to the Apple logo but that's it. No panels, no windows... nothing.

log:

```
2013-06-05 19:56:14,283 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2013-06-05 19:56:14,292 [      9]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: JetBrains WebStorm (build #WS-129.660, 04 Jun 2013 00:00) 
2013-06-05 19:56:14,292 [      9]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.8.4) 
2013-06-05 19:56:14,292 [      9]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406 (Apple Inc.) 
2013-06-05 19:56:14,292 [      9]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 20.45-b01-451 (Apple Inc.) 
2013-06-05 19:56:14,298 [     15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Didea.platform.prefix=WebStorm -Didea.paths.selector=WebStorm6 -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Didea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500 -Didea.no.jre.check=true -Didea.dynamic.classpath=false -Dnative.mac.file.chooser.enabled=true -Didea.jars.nocopy=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dapple.awt.fullscreencapturealldisplays=false -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Dswing.bufferPerWindow=false -Didea.fatal.error.notification=disabled -Didea.cycle.buffer.size=1024 -Dide.mac.show.native.help=false -Didea.popup.weight=heavy -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false -Didea.no.launcher=false -DCVS_PASSFILE=~/.cvspass -Didea.use.default.antialiasing.in.editor=false -Dcom.apple.mrj.application.live-resize=false -Didea.smooth.progress=false 
2013-06-05 19:56:14,311 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 13 ms 
2013-06-05 19:56:14,364 [     81]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Snappy library loaded (1.0.4) in 53 ms 
2013-06-05 19:56:17,503 [   3220]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:699)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:398)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGetOk(DialogWrapper.java:1460)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1435)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.i.l$0.run(l$0.java:103)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.i.l.a(l.java:109)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.e.y.a(y.java:282)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.e.y$3.a(y$3.java:401)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.i.n.b(n.java:112)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.i.n.access$200(n.java:16)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.i.n$3.actionPerformed(n$3.java:67)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:710)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:683)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
2013-06-05 19:56:17,506 [   3223]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JetBrains WebStorm 6.0.2  Build #WS-129.660 
2013-06-05 19:56:17,506 [   3223]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.6.0_45 
2013-06-05 19:56:17,506 [   3223]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2013-06-05 19:56:17,506 [   3223]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Apple Inc. 
2013-06-05 19:56:17,506 [   3223]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X
```

Comment: Check [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) for errors.

Comment: thanks, i paste it in the question. This is a new log file from 1 start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is fixed in WebStorm 6.0.2a (build 129.664), which is now available for download at http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/
Sorry for the problems.